# CKEditor - Pasting from Word changes font sizes

Tags: java, ckeditor, zk

I use CKEditor 3.6.4 with ZK 5.0.5 and I'm having an issue in copy-and-paste from Word (Office 2010). The browser is IE8.

The problem is that font-size 11pt becomes larger in CKeditor, the HTML result of pasting from Word is `<span style="font-size: medium;">`. Curiously, i'm not having this issue with other font sizes, for instance font-size 10pt becomes `<span style="font-size: 10pt;">` in CKEditor.

Here is ckeditor.js:

```
config.coreStyles_bold = { element : 'b', overrides : 'strong' };
config.font_names = 'Calibri;Open Sans;Arial;Times New Roman;Verdana;';
config.fontSize_sizes = '8/8pt;9/9pt;10/10pt;11/11pt;12/12pt;13/13pt;16/16pt;24/24pt;';
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV;
config.resize_enabled = false;
config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar';
config.toolbar_MyToolbar = [
    [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'TextColor', 'BGColor', '-', 'Link',
      'Unlink', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight',
      'JustifyBlock', '-', 'Maximize' ],
    [ 'Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'] ];    
config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = false;
config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = false;
config.ignoreEmptyParagraph = false;
```

Can you help me?

Thanks